# What happened when we override union fields in C?

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I am reading the implementation of the [Thompson algorithm](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/nfa.c.txt) for matching a regular expression in C.  I saw this snippet of code:

```
typedef union Ptrlist Ptrlist;

/*
 * Since the out pointers in the list are always 
 * uninitialized, we use the pointers themselves
 * as storage for the Ptrlists.
 */
union Ptrlist
{
    Ptrlist *next;
    State *s;
};

/* Create singleton list containing just outp. */
Ptrlist*
list1(State **outp)
{
    Ptrlist *l;

    l = (Ptrlist*)outp;
    l->next = NULL;
    return l;
}
```

But as I understand, in `union` type, all fields share the same memory. So why can we set `l->next=NULL` after casting `l=(Ptrlist*)outp;` because by doing that, we set that memory location to `NULL` and `l` will become `NULL`?

Comment: You first should read a good book on C programming, then read at least the wikipage on [union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) and [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But as I understand, in `union` type, all fields share the same memory.

Yes.

> So why can we set `l->next=NULL` after casting `l=(Ptrlist*)outp`; because
>   by doing that, we set that memory location to `NULL` and `l` will become
>   `NULL`?

No.

You seem to be confusing `l`, a *pointer to* a `PtrList`, with the `PtrList` object to which it points.  `l->next` designates a different object than does `l`, although both have type `PtrList *`.  Setting the value of the former does not affect the value of the latter.

Comment: The code in the link is more intricate than I thought.